# How to get SHOW CREATE TABLE without table borders made of dashes?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ddl

When I use SHOW CREATE TABLE in my MariaDb command line client I get this output for my table:

```
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| options | CREATE TABLE `options` (
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update_who` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Is it possible to get the output without all that table border made out of dashes and plus signs?

I want to get rid of it, because in my command line (Windows 10) it prints like this:
[image]

I use MariaDB 10.3.14

Comment: Not likely but if you made your command window really wide you would see that they are just there as an outline. They stack up like that because of the narrowness of the window.

Comment: Thanks, I see that in the code section in my question. But look how it looks like in my command window which is not very narrow (I placed a printscreen in my question). I think there is too many completely not necessary characters there.

Comment: It's still narrow enough to cause the wrapping you are seeing.

Comment: I use 1920x1080 resolution. The command was run and screenshot taken with maximized window. So how can it be too narrow? Should I have 1920*10 = 19 200px wide screen for this lines no to stack up? Come on :)

Comment: have you thought about using a gui instead of the comand line?

Comment: I have used GUI before, but now to speed up my workflow I have started using integrated command line terminal in my IDE to make some fast db structure check ups. It worked fine, but I was struggling with that "drawing" problems  With that \G answer it works smoothly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\G` as in `SHOW CREATE TABLE options \G`

## EXAMPLE

```
mysql> show create table mysql.db \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: db
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `db` (
  `Host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Db` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Select_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Insert_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Update_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Delete_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Drop_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Grant_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `References_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Index_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_tmp_table_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Lock_tables_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Show_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Execute_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Event_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Trigger_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Db`,`User`),
  KEY `User` (`User`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Database privileges'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: That's it! Thanks.